# Impedance matching in Transmitter Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, antenna, impedance-matching, transmitter

Consider the FM transmitter circuit from here (https://eeeproject.com/fm-transmitter-circuit/) with circuit diagram

[image]

In this question ([Antenna in Transmission & Receiver circuits](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/590047/antenna-in-transmission-receiver-circuits)) I was going to discuss in general how an antenna in such transmitter (or receiver) circuits may be realized (roughly: does it simply suffice to attatch there, where the antenna is drawn in the picture, any metal rod and that's all; or even if it's really neccessary to attatch there "something") and here I would discuss a further facet of my trial journey in the realm of antenna physics.

As far as a learned the motivation behind the practice of [Impedance matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching) is just to improve the efficiency of transmission/receiver circuits by choosing the "optimal" parameters for the antenna in a given circuit in order to reduce the energy loss.

Assume, we dealing with with our "toy example" from above and I want
to attach now a **matched antenna** to it (so an antenna with optimal parameters as far as I understand the priciple of "impedance mathcing" correctly) , instead of taking an "arbitrary" metal
rod. If what I wrote before is correct, then the only relevant parameter we can optimize is the length of the antenna rod.

How can I explicietly determine/ calculate the neccassary parameters for my antenna (in this case the only relevant parameter is the length of rod; so I have to determine the "optimal" length) from the parameters
of the other components of the circuit, in order to archive the optimal
matching for the antenna?

Comment: Make the single rod antenna a 1/4 wavelength long for enough output power to make the transmitter illegal. The capacitor values are much too high for the fM band. Anything moving towards or away from the antenna will change the capacitance of the LC which will change the radio frequency. The frequency will also change as the battery voltage runs down. The simple circuit is missing pre-emphasis so sounds received will be muffled with no high audio frequencies.

Comment: This circuit is so simple that the difference between a proper match and almost anything else will hardly be noticable. If you want a "proper" FM transmitter, you will need a much more complex circuit. There's **no point** in trying to do impedance matching if the circuit itself is has poor performance, which is the case here.

Comment: @Audioguru: What do you mean by "Make the single rod antenna a 1/4 wavelength long for enough output power to make the transmitter illegal."? especially I not understand what you by "making the transmitter illegal"

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: Yes, this circuit is simple, but from conceptional view, what should one do I one have (maybe a more complicated) receiver/transmission circuit, and one wan't to find the "matching" antenna. How one should start and and what ideas & calculations are involved?

Comment: *I not understand what you by "making the transmitter illegal"* In many countries you're not allowed to transmit **anything** in the FM band as that can disturb the reception on other receivers.

Comment: *How one should start and and what ideas & calculations are involved?* Many books have been written on that. You first need to learn about "small signal analysis" so that you can determine the "small signal output impedance" of a given circuit. Start by reading books on "RF circuit design".

Comment: Say we are dealing with a transmitter. We have all components attatched (so the parameters of other components are fixed) and the one part which should still be modified is the antenna. How conceptionally this should be done? Should one first replace the antenna by an equivalent circuit with at first unknown parameters $R_A, Z_A$ and then the condition from here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching) be applied?

Comment: *How conceptionally this should be done?* As I wrote: "Many books have been written on that." So start studying. We're not going to explain here what you can learn from studying the textbooks on this subject. And no, I'm not going to recommend any book.

Comment: ah ok, the "illegal" refered to juridical issues; no I don't want really to broadcast the stuff in illegal way, don't worry; only understand the physics behind, this might be considered as thought experiment

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: 
ok, so in sketchy words we can conceptually split the transmission circuit 
(for receiver similary) in the "main part" (in the image above 
that's the complete circuit except the antenna; at the place of antenna 
there is just an abstract "output" line) and the "antenna part". For the main part 
we can calculate the "output impedance" Z_M (since the parameters
in the main part of all components there are fixed). Ok, it might be
hard, but pricipally we can calculate this value, since we know of parameters of the main part.

Comment: What's next? My idea was to replace for the next the "antenna part" 
 by an equivalent circuit with at first unknown parameter Z_A, 
the antenna impedance, which "models" the antenna.
In order to fullfill the matching condition
according to en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching, 
the antenna impendance should satisfy Z_A =Z_M^*. 
Ok, that's what I understand. are my reasonings correct up 
to now?

Comment: Next, we know the "right" Z_A now. How this information
can be "translated" back in our initial aim, to determine
the optimal length of antenna?

Comment: Transistor collector where the antenna is attached is a high-impedance point of this oscillator. Assume it oscillates at 100 MHz, where wavelength is 3 M. A quarter-wavelength wire at that high-Z point may make it quit oscillating because 1/4 wavelength is high-Z at open end, but lower-Z at collector. A half-wavelength wire is high-Z at both ends - making it roughly impedance match. Any other lengths contribute either inductance or capacitance, affecting frequency of oscillation. Radiation resistance transfers *some* power out into space as well. Try antenna lengths 1/8 to 1/2 wavelength.